# How do you escape falling to your death in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing on my world, right with my friends on my pc. We were using the non-Java edition, and while I was away from my pc my brother apparently found it hilarious to destroy the spawn point and use a command block to teleport me under bedrock. And also, he is not willing to re edit what he did. Are there any ways to solve this problem without changing my game mode to Creative? My friends don’t know yet and I have no intention of being beat up by them tomorrow. Any help?

Comment: How would one go about destroying spawn point? Did he delete the whole map there?

Comment: "the non-Java edition" doesn't tell us which game you're actually playing. It could be MCPE, legacy console edition, Raspberry Pi edition, Minecraft 4K, Classic in browser, the Pokemon Go clone, the board game, "Minecraft dungeons", the story game that bought the naming rights, Lego, …

Comment: "beat up"? If you fear violence, immediately go to the police! And people who beat you aren't actually your friends.

Comment: why don't you want to use Creative mode? It's the most suitable case to use it on a survival world, and don't forget to destroy that command block (if you can't find it, you need to use the server console)

Comment: your brother already entered creative mode in order to obtain the command block. there is nothing wrong with going into creative mode again in order to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform must be Bedrock, plus if you want to get out, I suggest that getting in creative is more highly suggested and in need to destroy the command block. The procedure is also needed to repair. You can also tell your friends how you are feeling and what made you upset.

Answer (score -2):

You could just go into creative mode, fly up, destroy the command block, and then repair the damage.

Comment: "without changing my game mode to Creative"